# Windows 10 Store: You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages

Tags: cordova, windows-store-apps, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to release my application targetting Windows 10 (Universal Windows) based in Cordova to existing Windows Phone 8.1 store record.

After generating app package through Store - Create App Packages I get 19 MB file named `CordovaApp.Windows10_1.3.2.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle`. Then I upload this file to App Packages and get.

`CordovaApp.Windows10_1.3.2.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle 18.9 MB`

`Package acceptance validation error: You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages. Please upload the Store appxupload file and try again.`

I am working with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2
Note that I have already tried to

- Start new App record and upload Windows10 package
- Remove referencing projects and upload package
- Right click the project Store - Create App Packages
- Project - Store - Create App Packages

Comment: Project > Store > Create App Packages.  https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-windows-version-of-your-app

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for reply. As I wrote. I already tried this by right clicking on the project. I also tried to create package from the drop down menu but still same error.

Comment: Can you provide the list of plugins? Have you updated the VS to VS2015 update 2?

Comment: @AlanYao-MSFT Please see my updated post.

Comment: I'm not using Cordova, but found the same error for normal UWP app. Can you see `CordovaApp.Windows10_1.3.2.0_x86_x64_arm.appxupload` file located at the parent folder of the appxbundle? you should upload the appxupload file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that Visual Studio 2015 in order to improve performance of the app uses .NET Native compiler while Debugging. This features needs to be turned off while making the release packages. Either by explcitly in the .jsproj/.csproj

```
<EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>false</EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>
```

Or directly in project properties as described on this site: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps/

Answer (score 14):

It's even simpler I just found out when I came across this page. Do not upload the ..._arm.appxbundle from the latest subdirectory, but select, one directory up (in ...\Myproject\AppPackages) the latest:
Myproject_x.x.x.x_x86_arm_bundle.appxupload

That file will be accepted.
Would be great if this would have been a bit clearer in the error message. Or that this file should be called 'ThisIsForTheStore.appxupload'.

Comment: The funny thing is--the file type .appxbundle, which is what OP was using, is listed on the upload page as a supported file type. I had a similar issue just now with the .msixbundle file type, which is also listed as a supported file type. I am beginning to think .appxupload is the only type that Microsoft accepts.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Store only accepts the generated `.appxupload` package which by default can be found in `/AppPackages` folder.

Any other `.appx` packages are created for testing purposes only.