# Uploading packages to Windows Store for UWP apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

I have developed a UWP application using Visual Studio 2019 and Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2 and Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2. After creating the app packages for Windows Store, the folder contains the below files:

1. Add-AppDevPackage.resources(Folder)
2. Dependencies(Folder)
3. Add-AppDevPackage.ps1
4. XYZ_1.0.0.0_x64.appxsym
5. XYZ_1.0.0.0_x64.cer
6. XYZ_1.0.0.0_x64.msixbundle
7. Install.ps1

The app has also undergone Windows App Certification Kit Test and has passed all the test cases. When I try submitting the app packages(either the .msixbundle file or the way mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-your-app-package-upload-file-manually), I get the following error:

```
Package acceptance validation error: You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages. Please upload the Microsoft Store appxupload file and try again.
```

I also tried the way explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496537/windows-10-store-you-cannot-submit-pre-compiled-net-native-packages) and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps/) but failed utterly.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have used Sideloading apps while creating packages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create application package that contain `.appxupload` file

[image]

you can find more information from  :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps

Comment: Create your app package upload file manually
Place the following files in a folder:

One or more app packages (.msix or .appx) or an app bundle (.msixbundle or .appxbundle).
An .appxsym file. This is a compressed .pdb file containing public symbols of your app used for crash analytics in Partner Center. You can omit this file, but if you do, no crash analytic or debugging information will be available for your app.
Zip the folder.

Change the zipped folder extension name from .zip to .msixupload or .appxupload. I tried this as well but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to create a package submitted to the Microsoft Store, you need to do the following steps:

1. Have a developer account
2. Create an application in the [Partner Center](https://partner.microsoft.com/dashboard/home)
   [image: Imgur]
3. Associate your project with your application in Visual Studio, a certificate will be generated after the association (`Publish` -> `Associate App with the Store...`)
   [image: Imgur]
4. After the binding is completed, there will be a new option when packaging. Please select the package required to create the Microsoft Store. After the packaging is completed, a `.appxupload`(or `.msixupload`) file will be generated and you can upload it
   [image: Imgur]

Best regards.

Comment: I tried this way and also received the message "The association was successful." while associating. I also created the packages and also passed all cases of Windows App Certification Kit. However, packages folder still doesn't have .appxupload file. I have attached the images for reference. [image](https://imgur.com/a/RTBujHl)

Comment: If you checked **Generate artifacts to validate the app with Windows App Certification Kit.** During the package creation process, then Visual Studio will generate a test package for testing when packaging, this is the folder which shown in your picture. At the same time, the `msixupload` file should be in the parent directory of the test package folder (that is, the destination folder for your package). Of course, you can also uncheck that option during the packaging process so that Visual Studio will only generate `msixupload` files

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. Now you have a folder which name like `myApp_1.0.0.0_x64` (Is the folder shown in your screenshot). You can find `msixupload` (or `appxupload`) files in its parent folder. For example, the generated folder we set during packaging is `E:\Package\`. After packaging, we need to find the `.msixupload` file in `E:\Package\` instead of `E:\Package\myApp_1.0.0.0_x64\`.

Comment: @SamD: Did you ever manage to get the upload-bundle created?
Background of my question: In all apps I created, these file has been generated. Now I have a project, where the process runs as usual, but that bundle.appxupload is not being generated for some reason. 
I stumbled over your question on my research