# Unable to validate UWP application for microsoft store

Tags: windows, xamarin.forms, uwp, certificate, windows-store

I have developed a UWP application via Xamarin Forms. I am able to sideload the release bundle. But when I am trying to publish or associate the app to the Microsoft Store. Getting the below error. Any suggestions or input would be really appreciated. Thanks.

**Error:**
Unable to install Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4_2.42007.9007.0_x86_8wekyb3d8bbwe because the same package Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4_x86_8wekyb3d8bbwe is specified multiple times. Each package specified needs to be unique.

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: Sure. I have removed image and typed in the whole error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are running the local WACK Test for your app. Based on the error message, the Microsoft.UI.Xaml failed to install because it is installed before. The local WACK test uses your local device to test and it is optional. I'd suggest you upload your package to the store submission directly. When you upload your package to the store, there will be another Online WACK test for your app and the store will only check the result of the online WACK test.

Comment: This worked. But there are 2 other issues I faced which these 2 links helped me resolve the issue. 1.)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496537/windows-10-store-you-cannot-submit-pre-compiled-net-native-packages  2.)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951570/uwp-app-invalid-package-family-name-after-update-certificate      Thank you for the help. Really Appreciated

Comment: I have accepted  it. But Since I am new to stack overflow, it won't post my responses yet. Thank you for the help.

Comment: But I am using the wack test because I got an error with the submission in the Microsoft Store!